# Sum of two contraction mappings

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f$ and $g$ be two contraction mappings of a complete metric space $X$.
I am required to show whether or not the mapping $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is also a contraction mapping.
An exercise before I already proved that the compositions $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are contraction mappings of $X$. I think maybe I can use that result, but I'm not sure how.
Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: The problem as stated above makes no sense, because there's no such thing as $f(x)+g(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac 2 3 x$. Is $h(x)=f(x)+f(x)$ a contraction mapping ?

Comment: Ah I see, no this h is not a contraction mapping. I was thinking way too hard I think. Thank you!